# GitHub Appliances Test failover Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-enterprise

I am performing the test failovers on the primary devgit appliances and facing few issues. For that I have rebooted the server and now I am unable to access the UI.

Comment: Please provide details about the issues you are facing to understand better the problem, a well formulated question will help you to get a faster response

Answer (score -1):

Now the UI is up and running. The problem is I am not able to add the replicas to the new primary that I have promoted as the test failover is in progress.

Comment: Glad you were able to get an answer for your initial question. If you have a new issue, consider creating a new question.